# .NET 3.5 assembly start up functionality

Tags: .net

Currently I'm using System.Web.PreApplicationStartMethod in my .NET4 assembly to load much needed code.

How can I achieve this with the .NET 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mimic it in .NET 3.5, it's new functionality that is only introduced in .NET 4.0. the best I can think of is Application_Start, but this will not be the same.